# disable drag and drop on child table using Jquery sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to make a drag and drop feature on a table rows(tr). My table having child table under the main table (td). I have used Jquery UI sortable to archive the same and its working fine.
But my child table (tr) also automatically added as drag and drop features. I need only on main table.

Here is my table Structure -

```
<table id="mytable" class="grid">
    <thead>
        <tr><th class="index">No.</th><th>Year</th><th>Title</th><th>Group</th><th>Grade</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="index">1</td>
            <td>1969</td>
            <td>Slaughterhouse-Five</td>
            <td>Group</td>
            <td>A+</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="index">2</td>
            <td>1952</td>
            <td>Player Piano</td>
            <td>Group</td>
            <td>B</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="index">3</td>
            <td>1963</td>
            <td>Cat's Cradle</td>
            <td>Group</td>
            <td>A+</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="index">4</td>
            <td>1973</td>
            <td>Breakfast of Champions</td>
            <td>Group</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="index">5</td>
            <td>1965</td>
            <td>God Bless You, Mr. Rosewater</td>
            <td>Group</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="index">6</td>
            <td>1965</td>
            <td>God Bless You, Mr. Rosewater</td>
            <td>Group</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="index">7</td>
            <td>1965</td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name1</td>
                        <td>Addrs1</td>
                        <td>phn1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name2</td>
                        <td>Addrs2</td>
                        <td>phn2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name3</td>
                        <td>Addrs3</td>
                        <td>phn3</td>
                    </tr>
                </table
            </td>
            <td>Group</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery Code -

```
$(function(){
    var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
        var $originals = tr.children();
        var $helper = tr.clone();
        $helper.addClass('dragRow');
        $helper.children().each(function(index) {
            $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width());
            console.log($helper);
        });
        return $helper;
    };
    $("#mytable tbody").sortable({
        revert: true,
        start: function(e, ui){
            $(ui.placeholder).hide(300);
        },
        change: function (e,ui){
            $(ui.placeholder).hide().show(300);
        },
        cursor: "move",
        revert: 300,
        axis: "y",
        helper: fixHelperModified
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

I want to exclude Child table sortable which under a `<td>`. any assistance will be appreciated.

**https://jsfiddle.net/pLsk3tkx/1/**

Comment: Hi Sandy, Can you please put up your code in a fiddle and share us a working URL to test?

Comment: yeah Hi David I have added live jsfiddle inside the post.

Comment: Thanks. But the 'drag and drop' doesn't seems to be working in that fiddle.

Comment: I have update the link and its working fine on fiddle. please check